# Change JLabel text with a for-loop

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I need help to change Jlabel texts that is a loop, I need to try something type:

```
String[] inputs = {"nickname0", "nickname1", "nickname2", "nickname3", "nickname4", "nickname5", "nickname6", "nickname7", "nickname8", "nickname9"};
            for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
                inputs[i].setText("exemple" + i);
            }
```

or like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            (inputs + i).setText("exemple" + i);
        }
```

but this methods dont work, anyone have solution?

Comment: `inputs[i]` is a String ans String does not have `setText` what you want to do exactly?

Comment: In order to change a `JLabel`, you need a `JLabel` instance. Such objects are not in the provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually update the content of the String objects in the array not the JLabel objects used by your application.
So instead, add the JLabel objects in the array and iterate on them :

```
JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("nickname0");
JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("nickname1");
...

JLabel[] inputs = {lbl1, lbl2, ...};
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].setText("exemple" + i);
}
```

Comment: was bad, I think I did not explain it right, I had already created all jlabel, as you can see in print: [link](http://prntscr.com/jcghob)
I just want to change the value of all of them with FOR .

Comment: but in any case, I solved my problem thanks to your help, doing this: 'code' JLabel[] inputs = {nickname0, nickname1, nickname2, nickname3, nickname4, nickname5, nickname6, nickname7, nickname8, nickname9};
                for(int i = 0; i<dadosJogadores.length; i++) {
                    inputs[i].setText("exeple" + i);
                }